# Eclipse Java editor: insert current date in YYYYMMDD format?

Tags: java, eclipse, date, editor

The question is very similar to this one: [In Eclipse how to automatically print current date/time in the comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318805/in-eclipse-how-to-automatically-print-current-date-time-in-the-comments)  However, I'd like a format different from the default Mon, DD YYYY.  Template editor (Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates > New) lists ${year} variable but, strangely, no similar ${day} or ${month}.  Is there any place where I could ask to add them for the next release?  Or perhaps add them myself by modifying a specific plugin?  Thanks.

Comment: Actually the question is more similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131712/how-to-set-the-eclipse-date-variable-format - short answer: it's an open Eclipse bug/feature request