# How to write Author name and document detail in JSP using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, comments

How to write automatically 
auther name 
created date 
when I create jsp in Eclipse is there any shortcut or template available that work for me

in java file we annotation @author to write auther's name 
(i.e)

```
/**
    @auther xyz
*/
```

but what are the possible ways to write it in JSP

I want to write below option

```
Author:xyz
Document:xyzd.jsp
Created Date:22th sep 2013
```

Comment: why have you tagged `jstl` tag here ?

Comment: This link may be reference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318805/in-eclipse-how-to-automatically-print-current-date-time-in-the-comments

Answer (score 1):

You can change the jsp file formats under ,

```
Window -> Preferences
```

or still easier is to ,

[image]

to edit on clicking the [jsp templates](http://example.com) link while creating the new jsp

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse you will have to create a new jsp template and create a new template.For new template:Click on **Windows>Preferences>Web>JSP Files>Editor>Templates**.

Create a New Template and then specify your pattern there.As per convention:

`<%-- 
  - Author(s):
  - Date:
  - Copyright Notice:
  - @(#)
  - Description: 
  --%>`